# C# Event  doesn't fire when I change text in the textbox

Tags: c#, event-handling

The TextChanged event doesn't fire when the user changes the text. I think it may be an error with the generated code.

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
    }
```

Comment: What platform? ASP.NET? WinForms? Silverlight? Also, what is your question?

Comment: Why the downvotes? If you downvote, you really should leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: @BobHorn the downvotes are likely because there is no question here.

Comment: @jrummell Right, and I prefer when explicit questions are asked as well, but I think, in this case, it's easy to see that his question is: "Why isn't my event firing?" He should say what the problem is though. Is there an exception? Is the method invoked but doing the wrong thing? Etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't just add the method, you need to open the form, select the Textbox, view the Event tab in the properties window, then set your handler for the `TextChanged` event.

Answer (score 3):

Simple said: have it auto-wired via the GUI editor in visual studio by using the property/events pane and creating your event there.

The code above is your event handler function. Events are divided in a few parts

1. Event signature - how it will be called
2. Handler function(s) - conform to the signature
3. Event hook
4. Handler function added to hook
5. Event fired.

**Event signature**

```
public delegate void TextChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

**Handler function (your code)**

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text; }
```

Needs to conform to the signature above

**Event hook**
Where it says "i can raise this event"

```
public event TextChangedEventHandler TextChanged
```

**Handler added to function**

```
TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
```